# How to write a resume for a job you haven't done for years?

Tags: resume

I worked in a particular trade up until about 8 years ago. Since then I've been working in various IT development roles. I now have decided I'd like to go back to working in that trade.

How do you write a resume to downplay your recent experience(last 4 roles), while highlighting older experience?

Comment: This question is a bit broad for our community.  Can you narrow your question down to be a bit more specific?

Comment: I think the question also answers itself - you give more space on paper and provide more detail for the portion of your career that's relevant to the positions you're looking for, and you prepare to answer the inevitable "why are you switching back" question in an interview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would allocate more of your resume to describing the work and achievements you did 8 years ago. Pull out skills from your last 4 roles that are still relevant to the trade job or most jobs (e.g. communication, teamwork, leadership, etc) Be ready to have a good cover letter or story about why you want to go back and, if relevant, how your skills are still up-to-date having been out of the trade for 8 years.